# How to parse JSON and nest function (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, json, dom

I want to start this off by thanking anybody who is taking the time to read
this. I am very new to web development, so I understand this may have been explained already, however I haven't been able to find or figure out what I am trying to accomplish.

I am working on a project for school to use an API. I am using the Blizzard Entertainment World of Warcraft Game Data API. I have figured out how to parse the JSON Data to display the item attributes that I like, however I am running into the following issue:

I have to make two separate fetch requests, because the first API returns only the item attributes in an array, but I also need to display the image associated with each item. However, the request to retrieve an image only retrieves one image, specified by the item ID. Therefore, I need to call the image API for each item in the array of the first request.

Below, you may see the code I am working with:

```js
let imgArray = [];


function fetchData(y) {

  let urlDataString = 'https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/search/item?namespace=static-us&locale=en_US&name.en_US={searchTerm}&orderby=id&_page=1&str=&access_token=USVn0pwRxjTkED3oJmBbRLsfd1DiShIam1';
  let queryString = urlDataString.replace('{searchTerm}', y);
  
  function fetchMedia(x) {

    let urlMediaString = 'https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/media/item/{wowItemID}?namespace=static-us&locale=en_US&access_token=USVn0pwRxjTkED3oJmBbRLsfd1DiShIam1';
    
    console.log(urlMediaString.replace('{wowItemID}', x));
    
    }

  



  fetch (queryString)
  .then(response => {
            
    if (!response.ok){
        throw Error("ERROR");
    }
    return response.json();
}).then(data => {
  console.log(data.results);  
  const html = data.results.map(user => {
      return `
      <div class="Items">
        
        <p>${user.data.name.en_US}</p>
        <p>Item Level ${user.data.level}</p>
        <d>${user.data.inventory_type.name.en_US}</d>
        <d class="subclass">${user.data.item_subclass.name.en_US}</d>
        <p>Item Class: ${user.data.item_class.name.en_US}</p>
        <p>Item Subclass: ${user.data.item_subclass.name.en_US}</p>
        <p>ID: ${user.data.id}</p>
        <script>
          let getImage = fetchMedia(${user.data.id});
        </script>

      </div>
      `;
  }).join('');
  console.log(html);
  document
  .querySelector('#stats')
  .insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html);
}).catch(error =>{
  console.log(error);
});

}
```

```css
.Items {
    background-color: #010721;
    max-width: 362.5px;
    padding: 15px;
    color:white;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border: 1px solid #BEBFC1;
    
}

.Item_Icons {

 border-radius: 7px;
 border: 1px solid #BEBFC1;
 
}

.subclass {
    margin-left: 230px;
}

.speed {
    margin-left: 230px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div id="app"></div>
    

    <div id="stats"></div>

    



</body>

<!-- <script src="ItemMedia.js"></script> -->
<script src="WOWAPI.js"></script>
</html>
```

When I call the main API which returns the array of items, the html for the  inside the map is returning as plaintext instead of running the script. How can I fix this?

[Screenshot of Console/HTML Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBk0k.png)

I apologize in advance if the answer is obvious, but I am very new to this, thank you if anyone can help point me in the right direction.

Edit: Edit: I did try using a string template literal to alter to pass the ID into the image url

```
ex.) <img src="https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/media/item/${user.data.id}?namespace=static-us&locale=en_US&access_token=USVn0pwRxjTkED3oJmBbRLsfd1DiShIam1" />
```

but I got a CORB error in the console.

Comment: So your approach is a bit counter form to solving this problem. Many browsers will not respect you just adding script tags. Since scripts are handled by the JS Engine it is not always possible that adding them to the DOM the way you are will have them run.

Comment: I appreciate that guidance Henry, could you point me in the right direction to avoid the CORB error that using the string template literal yields?

Comment: On further inspection, it's only 1 of the 5 fetches has the CORS issue. That's likely an issue on the API side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have so far been unable to determine why certain API calls have a CORS error, but most do not. That said, I've made a solution to handle this issue, and, I think, gather most of the information you are looking for:

```js
function fetchData(searchTerm) {
    fetch(`https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/search/item?namespace=static-us&locale=en_US&name.en_US=${searchTerm}&orderby=id&_page=1&str=&access_token=USVn0pwRxjTkED3oJmBbRLsfd1DiShIam1`)
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw Error("ERROR");
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            const stats = document.getElementById('stats');

            Promise.all(data.results.map(user => {
                return fetch(`https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/media/item/${user.data.id}?namespace=static-us&locale=en_US&access_token=USVn0pwRxjTkED3oJmBbRLsfd1DiShIam1`,)
                    .then(innerRes => innerRes.json())
                    .then(innerResData => {
                        return {...user, ...innerResData}
                    })
                    .catch(() => {
                        // Catch CORS Error
                        return user
                    })
            }))
                .then(results => {
                    results.forEach((user) => {
                        const div = document.createElement('div');
                        div.className = 'Items';
                        const lines = [
                            `${user.data.name.en_US}`,
                            `Item Level ${user.data.level}`,
                            `${user.data.inventory_type.name.en_US}`,
                            `${user.data.item_subclass.name.en_US}`,
                            `Item Class: ${user.data.item_class.name.en_US}`,
                            `Item Subclass: ${user.data.item_subclass.name.en_US}`,
                            `ID: ${user.data.id}`
                        ];
                        for (let line of lines) {
                            const p = document.createElement('p');
                            p.innerText = line;
                            div.appendChild(p);
                        }

                        if (user.assets) {
                            for (let asset of user.assets) {
                                const i = document.createElement('img');
                                i.src = asset.value;
                                div.appendChild(i);
                            }
                        }
                        stats.appendChild(div);
                    });
                });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}
```

I tested this by putting in the console:

```
fetchData('honor')
```

It seemed to work well for the first 100 results.

You'll have to work out how to navigate the pagination as well if you intend to search for as large a result pool as 'honor'.

Interestingly, none of first 100 results had any CORS issues. I don't know what's special about the 5th result in the 'thunderfury' query, but it appears that it's an anomaly not the norm.